# Google Map Multiple marker from onMapReady

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add multiple marker in google map. The problem I am facing is, when the first marker is added rest are all not getting added, even though latitude and longitude values are different.

I am using google places API to get details and plotting the info in the google map.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng MyLoc = new LatLng(lati, lngi);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MyLoc).title("My Location"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MyLoc, 17.0f));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MyLoc, 17));
    if (places == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I have no places...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    Place[] items = new Place[places.size()];
    places.toArray(items);
    for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        double sLat = places.get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
        double sLng = places.get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();
        LatLng latlngg = new LatLng(sLat, sLng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latlngg)
                .title(places.get(i).getName())
                .snippet(places.get(i).getVicinity())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .alpha(0.7f));
    }

}
```

Comment: `LatLng latlngg = new LatLng(lati, lngi);` why dont u use sLat and sLng ?

Comment: Yes used that also but still same problem

Comment: `LatLng latlngg = new LatLng(sLat, sLng);` I think you should change like that, otherwise all markers are added at same point.

Comment: You have a copy/paste error, double sLng = places.get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat(); should be something like   double sLng = places.get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLongitude();

Comment: double sLat = places.get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
            double sLng = places.get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
            LatLng latlngg = new LatLng(sLat, sLng);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latlngg)

Comment: There is no error My Position marker is coming, rest of the marker not coming

Comment: There is no magic, just put breakpoint inside for loop and observe `latlngg` variable

Comment: I feel in onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) we can add only one marker need to find someother way. If I remove My Location marker, it adds the one marker from the FOR loop after adding one marker, its not showing other markers, that means in OnMapReady only one Marker it seems (or else something else might be wrong)

Comment: I just reviewed your code, if `places` is null or has zero item, then this code will not add any marker out of for `MyLoc` position

Comment: places has 20 records, I checked that clearly, FOR LOOP is going for 20 times in breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Your zoom level of 17 is too high. I fear your LatLng are falling out of map view. Cross check after significantly reducing the zoom level.